# Issue on Creating Custom Tax Term Dynamically From Another CPT Meta-box On Publish

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I have two Custom Post Types called `book` and `publisher`. The `book` has two Custom Fields (Metabox) `author_fname` and `author_lname` and the `publisher` has a Custom Taxonomy called `authors`

Now can you please let me know how I can use `book` metaboxes (`author_fname` and `author_lname`) to dynamically create a taxonomy ( `authors`) term for `publisher` as soon as the new Custom Post of `book` is published?

Here is the code I have

```
function add_cpt_term($post_ID) {
    $post = get_post($post_ID);
    $meta = get_post_custom($post); 
    $mfname = $meta['author_fname'][0];
    $mlname = $meta['author_lname'][0];
if (!term_exists($mfname. " " . $mlname, 'authors'))
        wp_insert_term( $mfname. " " . $mlname, 'authors', array('slug' => $mfname. " " . $mlname));
}
add_action('publish_book', 'add_cpt_term');
```

Not Getting any error but it is not publishing any term either